# Problema al unir chunks con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, y es que al subir un archivo pesado a un `input type="file"`, lo divido en `chunks` de 1MB y los mando al PHP, eso funciona correctamente.

El problema viene al tratar de unirlos, que no se hace. Se queda el archivo de pruebas que tengo (es de 7MB) en 7 trozos, y debería poderse unir todos en uno solo.

Aquí tengo el código que conseguí copiar de otra respuesta, con un par de modificaciones para que pueda funcionar (antes no leía y escribía contenido), pero no lo junta:

```
<?php
    
$target_path = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$sports = $_GET['file'];
$part =(string)$_GET['num'];
//$part = split("/\=/", $part);
$target_file = $target_path .$part. $sports;


// Open temp file
$out = fopen($target_file, "w");

if ( $out ) {
    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    $in = fopen($tmp_name, "r");
    if ( $in ) {
        while ( $buff = fread( $in, 1048576 ) ) {
            fwrite($out, $buff);
        }   
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné!

```
<?php
session_start();

$message = ''; 

$target_path = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
$num = $_POST['num'];
$num_chunks = $_POST['chunks'];
$namae = $_POST['namae'];



move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path.$num.$name);

// count ammount of uploaded chunks
$chunksUploaded = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= $num_chunks; $i++){
    if(file_exists($target_path.$i.$name)){
        ++$chunksUploaded;
    }
}

//avengers...
if($chunksUploaded == $num_chunks){
  
    //reassemble
    for($i = 0;$i <= $num_chunks; $i++){
        $file = fopen($target_path.$i.$name, 'rb');
        $buff = fread($file, 1048576);
        fclose($file);

        $final = fopen($target_path.$namae, 'ab');
        $write = fwrite($final, $buff);
        fclose($final);

        unlink($target_path.$i.$name);
    }
}
?>
```

Con este PHP consigo unir todos los chunks del file que suba al formulario, dentro de este lo que hago es subir cada chunk con un su numero correspondiente, en el PHP leerlos de forma binaria, y meter su contenido en un archivo nuevo llamado exactamente igual al original y después borrar todos los chunks con numero en su nombre:

```
function uploadFile(chunkFile, part, x, charged){
  //se ejecuta tantas veces esté dividido el archivo
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let fd = new FormData();
  let chunks = Math.max(Math.ceil(x.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK), 1);
  //let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];

  /*xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{uploadProgress(event, bar, x, charged)}, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);*/
  
  fd.append("file1", chunkFile);//con esto consigo el blob
  fd.append("num", part);//el numero de la parte que corresponde
  fd.append("chunks", chunks);//el numero de chunks que hay
  fd.append("namae", x.name);//con esto consigo el nombre del archivo completo

  xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Comment: Estás consumiendo recursos de forma innecesaria al abrir, guardar y cerrar el archivo final dentro del ciclo. Por otra parte, ¿probaste a subir dos o más archivos con el mismo nombre? Creo que el segundo archivo se agregará al final del existente. Falta una validación para sobrescribir o asignar nuevo nombre, dependiendo de lo que necesitas o quieres hacer.

Comment: Si, tengo otra pregunta con otro problema del JS y subí al 100% el archivo completo. Seguramente se pueda pulir un montonazo, pero bueno. Y si, puedo subir cuantos archivos quiera de la nueva forma.